# Django-disqus: manage.py not accepting API key

Tags: python, django, api, disqus

I'm trying to integrate disqus into my Django app. I got the API key and put it in `settings.py`, but when I tried to start the local server, it is giving me an error.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED APPS = [
    ...
    'disqus',
]

DISQUS_API_KEY = 'key'
DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME = 'website_shortname'
```

Of course I've put the actual key and shortname. The error I'm getting:

```
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

help

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full traceback for the error. `NameError` indicates that you are using the word `key` as a variable, instead of a string - so double-check your actual code to look for where you are using that word.

Comment: Yeah never mind, I solved the error